# how can i merge multiple joins in mysql (sample query given)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I need to have below join repeated for multiple students. How can optimize and write it as a single query?

```
select * from marks mar
join subject subj ON mar.subject_id=subj.subject_id
join student std ON subj.student_id = std.sutdent_id
Where std.student_name="xyz" and std.location="abc" and age="18"

select * from marks mar
join subject subj ON mar.subject_id=subj.subject_id
join student std ON subj.student_id = std.sutdent_id
Where std.student_name="ccc" and std.location="kkk" and age="19"
```

Comment: mysql or sql server?

Comment: What's with the two sql-server tags then?

Comment: Consider using the `in` clause in your query instead of a 1 to 1 equality check. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will parse in MySQL:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    marks mar
JOIN    subject subj
ON      subj.subject_id = mar.subject_id
JOIN    student std
ON      std.student_id = subj.student_id
WHERE   (std.student_name, std.location, age) IN (('xyz', 'abc', 18), ('ccc', 'kkk', 19))
```

but not give a better execution plan.

Alternatively, use this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    marks mar
JOIN    subject subj
ON      subj.subject_id = mar.subject_id
JOIN    student std
ON      std.student_id = subj.student_id
WHERE   (std.student_name, std.location, age) = ('xyz', 'abc', 18)
        OR
        (std.student_name, std.location, age) = ('ccc', 'kkk', 19)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is ...

```
select * from marks mar
join subject subj ON mar.subject_id=subj.subject_id
join student std ON subj.student_id = std.sutdent_id
Where 
    (std.student_name="xyz" and std.location="abc" and age="18")
    OR
    (std.student_name="ccc" and std.location="kkk" and age="19")
```

...oversimplifying it?